# Partition Orders table by arbitrary start and end day-of-month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following fairly standard *Orders* table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orders](
    [bill_product_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Bill_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [TenantId] [int] NULL,
    [Product_type] [int] NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NULL,
    [Customer_cost] [numeric](18, 10)
)
```

The following query gives me the start_date and end_date of each Month for which there are records in the table `orders`

```
SELECT distinct DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(bill_date,-1)) as start_date,
       EOMONTH(bill_date) as end_date
    FROM orders
```

Example resultset:

> start_date end_date
>
> ---
>
> 2020-07-01 2020-07-31
>
> 2020-08-01 2020-08-31

Now we need to change the 'Billing Cycle' so instead of starting on the 1st of the month, and ending on the last day of the month, we need the start of the billing cycle to be the 26th of the month, with the end being the following 25th day of the month (don't ask).

I'm sure I can determine the end_date given the start date, but I'm unsure the best way to partition the data into 26th-to-25th of the month segments.  Please suggest an effecient way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DECLARE @bill_date DATE = '2020-08-12'

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@bill_date), MONTH(@bill_date), 26)
      ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@bill_date), MONTH(@bill_date) + 1, 25)
```

But your way is valid, too and can be enhanced.

---

As you pointed, it should be:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@bill_date), MONTH(@bill_date) - (CASE WHEN DAY(@bill_date) >= 26 then 0 else 1 end) , 26);
```

in order to ensure dates smaller than `26` remain in the current interval, not the next one like in my original solution.

Comment: this gives the *next* interval starting on 26th Aug.  I tried subtracting 1 from both 'Month' parts, but that doesn't work if the date given is '2020-07-30' - it evaluates to June 26th when it should be July 26th

Comment: For `2020-07-30` I get `2020-07-26` and `2020-08-25`. Is not that what you need?

Comment: yes, but if given '2020-08-12' the same funtion returns a future date - not the current interval.  But DATEFROMPARTS helped me find the real solution: SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@bill_date),  MONTH(@bill_date) - (CASE WHEN DAY(@bill_date) >= 26 then 0 else 1 end) , 26);

Comment: @Black I understand the logic now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @gotqn, I can use DATEFROMPARTS as follows

```
 SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@bill_date),  
         MONTH(@bill_date) - (CASE WHEN DAY(@bill_date) >= 26 then 0 else 1 end), 
         26) as start_date
        ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@bill_date),  
         MONTH(@bill_date) + (CASE WHEN DAY(@bill_date) >= 26 then 1 else 0 end),
         25) as end_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract 26 days and use `datefromparts()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(yyyymm_start), MONTH(yyyymm_start), 26) as start_date,
       DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(yyyymm_end), MONTH(yyymm_end), 25) as end_date
FROM orders o CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEADD(DAY, -26, BILL_DATE),
              DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, -26, BILL_DATE))
             )
     ) as v(yyyymm_start, yyyymm_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use dateadd to "move" you billing cycle.

I assume that  then you query

```
  declare @billDate date = '2020-07-16'
 SELECT distinct DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@billDate)) as start_date,
       EOMONTH(@billDate) as end_date, 'Original' as query
    --FROM orders


 SELECT distinct DATEADD(DAY,26,EOMONTH(@billDate,-1)) as start_date,
       dateadd(day,25,EOMONTH(@billDate) )as end_date, 'Modified' as query
    --FROM orders
```

will result in

```
start_date end_date   query
---------- ---------- -------- 
2020-07-01 2020-07-31 Original
         
start_date end_date   query
---------- ---------- -------- 
2020-07-26 2020-08-25 Modified
```

Comment: this has the same problem as @gotqn's original answer, i.e. for '2020-08-10' it returns the *future* interval 2020-08-26 to 2020-09-25

Comment: fixed, added a -1 to the eomonth function

Comment: No.  Now it returns the wrong (previous) interval for the value '2020-07-30'

Comment: please post expected start/end date for a given set of billing date

Comment: it's all in the original post, and also in the answer by @gotqn.  Don't worry anyway it's already been answered correctly